# How to create a delete link for comments in Admin Comment Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please help. I'm just learning rails. I need in managing all site's comments in Admin dashboard page. But I couldn't make delete links.

```
class Admin::CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  def destroy
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comment = @commentable.comments.find(comment_params)
    @comment.destroy
    if @comment.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Comment Destroyed!"
      redirect_to :back
   end
  end

  private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :user_id)
    end


    def find_commentable
      params.each do |name, value|
        if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
          return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
        end
      end
      nil
    end
end
```

views/admin/index.html.erb

```
<%= render @comments %>
```

views/admin/_comment.html.erb

```
<tr>
  <td><%= comment.body %></td>
    <td><%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %></td>
    <td><%= t(comment.commentable_type) %></td>
    <td><%= comment.commentable_id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "edit"  %>
    | <%= link_to 'Delete', [:admin, comment], :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %></td>
</tr>
```

In my routes comments resources:

```
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :companies do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :cabinets do
      resources :comments
  end
  namespace :admin do
    get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'
    resources :articles do
      resources :comments
    end
    resources :companies do
      resources :comments
    end
    resources :cabinets do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
```

Comment: please add routes from config/routes.rb

Comment: sorry. forgot about it. routes added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your routes rails generates paths like `admin_articles_comment(@article, @comment)` (the same: `[:admin, @article, @comment]`), so if you want it like that you should use

`link_to [:admin, comment.commentable, comment], method: :destroy, confirm: 'You sure?'`

But that may require you to specify controller in your routes, or to create other controllers (check `rake routes` to see where which path directs to)

On the other hand, you can use `shallow: true` in your routes like that

```
namespace :admin do
    get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'
    resources :articles do
      resources :comments, shallow: true
    end
    resources :companies do
      resources :comments, shallow: true
    end
    resources :cabinets do
      resources :comments, shallow: true
    end
  end
```

and it should be working with your current setup (links, controller) (although I've never used this myself), here is some info about that: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting

Comment: It didn't work for me :( I have an error **undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass** in controller line '@comment = @commentable.comments.find(comment_params)'